# Search PL/SQL Code

Tags: oracle, search, plsql

SELECT * from ALL_OBJECTS returns the names of various procedures/packages/tables/other db objects. I want to look inside the PL/SQL code for a matching string.  How do I do this?

Something like: (pseudocode)  SELECT * FROM all_code WHERE line_of_code like '%mytext%'

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use something like:

```
    SELECT * 
      FROM USER_SOURCE 
     WHERE type='PACKAGE' 
       AND NAME='PACKAGE_NAME' 
  ORDER BY type, name, line;
```

There are many options, check out the USER_SOURCE table.

To search ALL code for a String:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM ALL_SOURCE
   WHERE UPPER(text) LIKE UPPER('%what I am searching for%')
ORDER BY type, name, line
```

Note that view code is not included in the `_SOURCE` tables.  View code is stored in `[USER|ALL|DBA]_VIEWS.TEXT` which is a LONG column and difficult to query.

Comment: Or ALL_SOURCE WHERE OWNER = [schema]

Comment: You might want to "ORDER BY type, name, line" to make the results clearer.

Comment: Make it case insensitive: where upper(text) like upper(%what I am searching for%')

Comment: I don't believe all_source will show package bodies owned by other users.  You can use dba_source to see those if you have access.